# how do i use group by only on date from datetime in LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, date, datetime

i have this LINQ query

```
var data = (from orders in db.Orders
        group orders by orders.OrderDate into dateGroup
        select new OrderDateGroup()
        {
            OrderDate = dateGroup.Key,
            OrderCount = dateGroup.Count()
        }).Take(10);
```

orders.OrderDate is DateTime but i want to group only on the basis of Date

Comment: What kind of LINQ are you using, what is `db`? Is it Linq-To-SQL, Linq-To-Entities, Linq-To-DataSet, Linq-To-Objects? If it was L2Objects you could simply use `group orders by orders.OrderDate.Date`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use canonical functions:

```
group orders by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(orders.OrderDate) into dateGroup
```

***Additional info:***

`EntityFunctions` methods are called ***canonical functions***. And these are a set of functions, which are supported by all Entity Framework providers. These canonical functions will be translated to the corresponding data source functionality for the provider. Canonical functions are the preferred way to access functionality outside the core language, because they keep the queries  portable.

You can find all canonical functions [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626(v=vs.110).aspx) and all Date and Time Canonical Functions [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, don't forget to include `System.Data.Objects` namepsace from `System.Data.Entity.dll`.

***Note:***
If you are using EF6, then you must consider to change `EntityFunctions` to [`DbFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). And don't forget to include `System.Data.Entity` namepsace from `EntityFramework.dll`.

Comment: yeah i was trying the canonical functions.. but i don't know exactly in which namespace its available.. i am using entityframework 6.0 can you help with this

Comment: @Shri As I know in EF6, they have replace `EntityFunctions` with `DbFunctions`. Check with that.

Comment: yup! that worked.. thanks brother :) actually i am new to this.. thanks again and all the best :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code below by getting Date of DateTime (*I am not sure if it works in LINQ to Entities*):

```
var data = (from orders in db.Orders
        group orders by orders.OrderDate.Date into dateGroup
        select new OrderDateGroup()
        {
            OrderDate = dateGroup.Key,
            OrderCount = dateGroup.Count()
        }).Take(10);
```

Comment: that does not work brother.. i've already tried that.. anyways thanks :)